# mocha times out on failed assertions with Q promises

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, q

Why does mocha timeout when an assertion fails inside a Q future? You also don't get to see the assertion failure when this happens. This does not happen if I just use callbacks. How should I write this while still using futures but get to see the assertion error instead of a timeout?

```
var Q = require('q');
function hack() {
  var ret = Q.defer();
  ret.resolve(true);
  return ret.promise;
}

it('test', function(done) {
  hack().then(function(bool) {
    assert(false);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the assertion even being reached? Mocha should definitely report a failed assertion. If it times out, that usually means the code isn't being run in the first place.

Comment: Removing the `assert(false);` statement ends up with a pass, so I'm pretty sure it's being reached.

Comment: Oh haha, just realized, your assertion exception is being caught by Q, per the [spec](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#point-60).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The assertion call throws an exception, which is caught by Q in order to properly conform to the promises [spec](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#point-60). So mocha never reaches `done()`, nor does it see an exception thrown. You could do something like this:

```
it('test', function(done) {
  hack().then(function(bool) {
    assert(false);
    done();
  }).catch(function(err){
    done(err);
  });
});
```

[edit] Alternatively, you can omit the `done` argument altogether and just return the promise directly from the test function, in which case mocha will pass/fail the test based on the outcome of the returned promise:

```
it('test', function() {
  return hack().then(function(bool) {
    assert(false);
  });
});
```

...which is a nice way to simplify your test functions. Props to Taytay elsewhere in this thread for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks! Good catch. Alternatively just use hack().done(...), although it looks kind of weird due to the done parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Mocha now supports promises in unit tests, so you can just return the promise instead of relying upon calling `(done)` from a then handler. It's easier and safer (because you won't forget to call done)

So you could just write:

```
it('test', function() {
  return hack().then(function(bool) {
    assert(false);
  });
});
```

That would fail because the promise would fail, and Mocha would detect it.

This is from the Mocha docs in the section "Working with Promises": https://mochajs.org/

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer now that Mocha supports promises.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on [greim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987721/485048) including what [callumacrae added in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986313/mocha-times-out-on-failed-assertions-with-q-promises#comment47150251_23987721), you can do it like this:

```
it('test', function(done) {
  hack().then(function(bool) {
    assert(false);
    done();
  }).catch(done);
});
```